# Why the line in this D3 chart isn't properly displayed when updated?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm a beginner with D3.js and I want to display a dynamic line chart where the line is always growing with random fluctuations.

I don't need an X axis but I'd like to get a dynamic Y axis based on the last point inserted in the line.

```
var n = 40,
    random = function(min, max) { return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; },
    data = d3.range(n).map(random);

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([1, n - 2])
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 100])
    .range([height, 0]);

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d, i) { return x(i); })
    .y(function(d, i) { return y(d); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left"));
var path = svg.append("g")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
  .append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);

var min = 0, max = min + 40;
tick();

//Update the chart
function tick() {
  // push a new data point onto the back
  var r = random(min, max);
  data.push(r);
  min += 10;
  max += 10;

  // update Y Axis
  var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([r - 20,r + 20]).range([height, 0]);
  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");
  svg.selectAll(".y.axis").call(yAxis);

  // redraw the line, and slide it to the left
  path
      .attr("d", line)
      .attr("transform", null)
    .transition()
      .duration(500)
      .ease("linear")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + ",0)")
      .each("end", tick);
  // pop the old data point off the front
  data.shift();
}
```

**JSFiddle :** https://jsfiddle.net/ugj8g9wu/

If I didn't increase the min / max and don't update the Y Axis everything is ok.

But with the code above, my line quickly go above the the Y axis, which doesn't make any sens since the randomized value is include in the domain of the Y axis...

Could you tell me what's going on and why my line isn't properly displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is a bit hidden. In `tick()`, you made a new `y` to handle the new `domain` and `range`, but you only updated `yAxis` with this `y`. What about the `line` which is still referencing the original `y`? It also needs update! You can either add code to update the `line`:

```
// update Y Axis
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([r - 20,r + 20]).range([height, 0]);
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");
svg.selectAll(".y.axis").call(yAxis);

// NEW CODE
line.y(function(d, i) { return y(d); });
```

Or (better I think), instead of creating a new `y` every tick, you can modify the existing one, saving all the efforts to assign it to everywhere else using it. Just change this line:

```
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([minY, maxY]).range([height, 0]);
```

into:

```
y.domain([minY, maxY]);
```

Then you'll be able to see the newest point coming in the right.

But there's one more problem with the code: you are increasing the value too quickly so that it's hard to see old points on the chart, so I tuned the arguments a bit to make it look better. Ideally, the `minY` and `maxY` should be calculated according to the values in `data`, not guessing magic boundarys. :)

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gbwycmrd/

Comment: Since my issue is fixed now, I updated the domain based on the average value of data displayed (and not the last value inserted). The result is not bad. I leave it here if it can help someone : https://jsfiddle.net/gbwycmrd/2/